# How does one open a tensorboard port in Linux?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have some tensorboard data and I want my server to let me see the data. I don't want to have to send the tensorboard data files to my computer, so it would be ideal if I can just access them remotely. How does one do that? I would assume that the server would just host it as a normal website? What are the Tensorboard commands for this?

I know that locally one can do:

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory
```

and then go to the browser to do:

```
http://localhost:6006/
```

but is it possible to the equivalent from a server and then just read the data in my local browser/computer from the server?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that there is no firewall preventing access to port 6006 from the outside, and that your server's address is `server.example.com` you should be able to simply type `http://server.example.com:6006` into your browser and have it work.

In case of a restrictive firewall, tunneling the tensorboard port over SSH using [Local Port Forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Local_Port_Forwarding) is a good approach (this is also more secure than opening random ports publicly). When logging in to your server, you could type (for instance):

```
ssh -L 12345:localhost:6006 server.example.com
```

After that, start tensorboard on the server as usual, and you will be able to access it at `http://localhost:12345` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

mvoelske instructions for setting up port forwarding are correct. If you have administrative privileges on the machine, you can open port 6006 to your IP address using the following commands:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <insert your ip> --dport 6006 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 6006 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The iptables change can be saved with the following command:

```
$ sudo service iptables save
```

Note that this is for CentOS v6 and below. CentOS v7 and above used Firewalld by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reached this stackoverflow question because you are troubleshooting a previously working TensorBoard setup, you might consider adding the --bind-all flag to your command line.

```
$ tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory --bind-all
```

This resolved my problem reaching TensorBoard by URL within an internal network.

```
http://my_server.company.com:6006
```